# Reparametrization Example

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization

from Elementary Differential Geometry By Andrew Pressley

A parametrized curve $\overline {\gamma}\colon(\overline {\alpha},\overline {\beta})\to R^n$  is a reparametrization of a parametrized 
curve $
 {\gamma}\colon( {\alpha}, {\beta})\to R^n$ if there is a smooth bijective map $\phi\colon(\overline {\alpha},\overline {\beta})\to( {\alpha}, {\beta})$ 
(the reparametrization map) such that the inverse map $\phi^{-1}\colon( {\alpha}, {\beta})\to(\overline {\alpha},\overline {\beta})$ is smooth and $\overline{\gamma}(\overline{t})=\gamma(\phi(\overline{t}))$
for all $\overline{t}\in(\overline {\alpha},\overline {\beta}).$

the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ has a parametrization 
$\gamma(t)=(cost,sint)$.
 Another parametrization is 
${\overline{\gamma}(t)}=(sint,cost)$ 
(since $sin^2t + cos^2t = 1$).

To see that $\overline{\gamma}$ is a reparametrization of $\gamma$, we have 
to find a reparametrization map $\phi$ such that 
$(cos\phi(t),sin\phi(t)) = (sin t, cost)$.

One solution is $\phi(t)=\pi/2 — t$.

My question is,for $\phi$ to be a solution $\phi$ must be bijective smooth map.I accept $\phi$ is smooth.I can also proved this is injective.But I am unable to show that $\phi$ is surjective.How can I prove this?

Comment: You should start by giving the intervals for your problem. Also, the definition of reparametrization should include a requirement that $\phi$ is an increasing function (or else you can end up going backwards on the curve).

Comment: i took $\phi\colon[0,2\pi]\to[0,2\pi]$ I think, i should have taken open interval whose length is greater than $2\pi$

Comment: Well, if you want to go once around the circle you have to use something that's not an open interval, so Pressley should have worked with a general interval here, not necessarily an open interval. At any rate, I still complain that your reparametrization goes *backwards* around the circle, which is actually a different curve from the perspective of differential geometry. But you can prove surjectivity if you choose intervals correctly. Your function $\phi$ clearly doesn't map $[0,2\pi]$ to $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: can you suggest me a good interval to work with.I am not getting what you mean about reparametrization going backward

Comment: Well, start with $t=0$, plot the point, go to $t=\pi/4$, plot the point, etc. Are you going around the circle counterclockwise or clockwise? If $\phi(t)=\pi/2-t$, to what interval does $[0,2\pi]$ map by $\phi$?

Comment: If $\phi(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$ , $\phi$ maps interval $[0,2\pi]$ maps to $[-2\pi,2\pi]$

Comment: No. Graph the function carefully. I'm not sure how much math you've studied, but differential geometry (with all the multivariable calculus and linear algebra) may be too much for you right now.

Comment: Is it $[\frac{-3\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Comment: yes i accept that.But I really want to improve.You can suggest me reference book for Differential Geometry.